# Error Invalid Request

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-plus

I tried to create the Google+ O Auth2 API Key inside the google developer console. Everytime i try to add a name and save it i yust got the response.

> Fehler
>
> Die Nutzeranfrage ist ungültig. Bitte überprüfen Sie Ihre URL und
>   versuchen Sie es erneut.

"Error, Your request is invalid. Please check your URL and try again". Does anyone have a idea what there could be wrong? Is it a defect on google or did i something wrong?

http://bild-speichern.de/dn.jpg